# return list of Xelement names

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath, linq-to-xml

I got an XDocument structure as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<body>
 <ControlSettings>
  <Manual-B nudA="20" nudB="3" nud=D"4"  />
  <Manual-A nudA="2" nudB="33" nudD="4"  />
  <Manual-C nudA="20" nudB="20" nudD="40" />
  <another value="true"  />
 </ControlSettings>
 <Score>
  <Manual-F result="fail" />
 </Score>
</body>
```

I am trying yo get out a sorted list of only the names in controlsettings So that string list should contain :

- another
- Manual-A
- Manual-B
- Manual-C

How to do that with Xdocuments using xpath / linq ?
I tried below but it doesnt seam to work

```
IEnumerable <string> names =  doc.XPathSelectElements
("..//body//ControlSettings").Select(e => e.Name.LocalName);
   /* other things i tried:
   List<string>mnames = doc.Root.Element("..//controlsettings").
   var query = from x in doc.Descendants("//body//ControlSettings")
    */
 foreach (string localname in names)Console.WriteLine(localname);
```

Comment: `"Manual-F"` (with quotes) is not a valid element.

Comment: yeah right thats a typo i fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all nodes within a document using `Descendants`

```
xmlDoc.Descendants()
      .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName.Contains("Manual"))
      .Select(e => e.Name.LocalName)
      .OrderBy(e => e)
      .ToList();
```

Or if that's to broad, and you want to be specific to the ControlSettings group, you can dig down like below

```
xmlDoc.Elements("ControlSettings")
      .Descendants()
      .Select(e => e.Name.LocalName)
      .OrderBy(e => e)
      .ToList();
```

Comment: above is usefull (please dont remove), but i'd like to get a list out of it with only the sorted item names below ControlSettings . As used to fill another combobox pulldown), and although i used manual it can have any name.

Comment: @user3800527 I've updated the code to order the names, and then return a list.

Comment: Well i got it working with only a slight adjustment (added "body"  elements):
xmlDoc.Elements("body").Elements("ControlSettings").Descendants().Select(e => e.Name.LocalName).OrderBy(e => e).ToList();
thanks